# Different Case's Created Date fieldApiName for Case's list view

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, list-view, case-object

I have custom logic to create listview with filters for any object in SF using metadata api.

- I noticed when I try to upadate `All Opened Cases` listview and add filter logic `CreatedDate equals TODAY` (put CASES.CREATED_DATE_DATE_ONLY api name for metadataapi) it's saved.
- But after refreshing listview `getListInfoByName` wire returned `label = null` and `fieldApiName = null` in filter object(listview is crushed).
- If I create the same filter and update listview (put `CASES.CREATED_DATE` api name for metadataapi) it works fine and `getListInfoByName` wire is not crushed.
- In another sanboxes it works fine with `CASES.CREATED_DATE_DATE_ONLY` instead of `CASES.CREATED_DATE`.

So my question is what is the diffrence between sandboxes (some enabled features and etc.)? All sanboxes works fine with `CASES.CREATED_DATE_DATE_ONLY` and one only needs `CASES.CREATED_DATE`.

Thanks.

I need understand the difference between my sanboxes or smth like that